# java не видит директорию WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

web.xml в директории IDEAProject/demo/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

в этой строке

/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml

пишет что не видит эту директорию (WEB-INF) и предлагает создать. создает по пути

IDEAProject/demo/WEB-INF/

## не знаю что делать

после закрытия проекта и заново открытия в web.xml в строке

```
 <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
```

сервлет должен быть замапен
а в строке

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
```

не могу резолвить сервлет dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

В Idea по дефолту (без перенастройки артефактов сборки) WEB-INF ожидается в корне, то есть в вашем случае на одном уровне с src.
Просто перенести в IDEAProject/demo/WEB-INF/ будет лучшим решением. Важно еще отметить что WEB-INF это не пакет, а именно директория.

Вы конечно можете зайти в File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts и пошаманить там, но это уже по ситуации.